# Where can I get a printable version of a Monero Paper Wallet to be used as gifts?

Tags: cold-storage

There doesn't seem to be any printable paper wallets like bitaddress.org but for Monero. I only found ones that generate 24 word seeds for your wallet which you have to write down manually. I want to be able to print out a nice graphic with QR codes to give as a gift.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably seen the paper wallet at the Monero.how site. The site explains:

> For security reasons, we chose to create a paper wallet that requires
>   us to write the seed onto it with a pen instead of printing the
>   information directly onto the wallet. This is to avoid security
>   threats from compromised printers and compromised smartphone QR
>   readers. When you print something, there is a good chance that the
>   images are being sent unencrypted across your network and stored
>   unencrypted in the printer's memory even after the printing is
>   complete. Because printer firmware tends not to be security hardened,
>   it is not inconceivable that a virus could exist either now or in the
>   future that would scan all print jobs for anything resembling a
>   cryptocurrency key and transmit it to an attacker. We sleep better at
>   night knowing that we used a pen.

If you wanted to use an existing paper wallet and modify it to include a QR code instead of the written seed words, then the first question you'd want to ask is "what should the QR code contain?".

If there is a specific app you know of that can scan QR codes that could directly read a 32 byte sequence representing the wallet seed, then that would be the most compact QR code representation.

However, anyone using the standard GetMonero.org desktop wallet would find that QR code useless. Therefore I'd recommend you create a QR code that simply includes the plain text seed words, which someone could scan and use to more easily enter the seed words into any Monero wallet. Be sure to download QR code creating software rather than using a web site to create the QR code. You would not want to accidentally use a hacked web site that is looking out for cryptocurrency keys that it can steal funds from.

Comment: i'm not that paranoid. these are trivial amounts of $5 - $50 to be used as gifts. Imagine gifting Monero to your 17 year old nephew or grand parents a piece of paper of your scribbled handwriting of 24 words on it and telling them "merry christmas". I don't think that would look like a good gift at all. But thanks for informing me of the future of potential printer viruses. Let's be practical sometimes, we don't need to wear a tin foil hat everyday.

Comment: You're right that most people would probably be fine. However, there is already malware that monitors your clipboard and steals funds (see https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/evrial-trojan-switches-bitcoin-addresses-copied-to-windows-clipboard/) There are also all sorts of "free" QR code readers available for phones that might report all scanned codes back to the authors. The recipient might end up using their phone to scan the QR, and then email themselves the seed to use on their desktop. Now you have to worry about email security. It's a minefield out there.